# Downloading multiple pdf's via wget into one output...issue

Tags: pdf, wget

I have an issue with wget that I'm experiencing.  I'm working on a studio where I download multiple pdf's via wget and I export them into a master file.  The code that I'm utilizing is:

```
wget -i wgetURL [which contains all of my urls] -O wgetURLDownloads
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is each iteration of a download overwrites the previous download.  So, where I'm expecting to see multiple files, I'm only seeing the one.

Any suggestions?

TL;DR:  I'm using wget to download multiple (60+) pdfs and outputting them as one file.  It's not working as expected though.  Halp!

Comment: How exactly do you want them to be converted into one file? Simply appending the contents of one into another will (I suspect) corrupt the document entirely. If you want to actually merge the pages into a single doc, that would take something more sophisticated.

Comment: I would like to first try and append the contents to each other.   If that doesn't work, then I'll try the other option

Comment: @NathanMayberry There's zero chance that will work; that's not how the PDF file format works. You're going to need a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: While concatenating pdfs will not create a multi-page document, I think "why isn't this wget command working as expected" is a valid question.  According to my interpretation of the man page it should work, even it won't produce a valid pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Download the files individually and use PDFtk to merge them.